# How to insert excel Cell Values to a list?

Tags: java, excel, list, arraylist, apache-commons

so I read data from a excel file

```
private static void excelRead(String fileName) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException 
{    
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fileName));
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
//Loop for getting data from excel
for (Row row: sheet)
    {
        for(Cell cell: row)
        {
            String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    workbook.close();
}
```

I cannot resolve, how I should write cellValue's into `List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();`

I tried using diffrenets ways, but I cant find a way.

Edit1: Student Class

```
public class Student extends Person {
private Calendar startStudyYear;
private Calendar endStudyYear;

public Student(String ID, String name, String surName, academicDeggre academicDeggre, Calendar birthDay, Integer age, Sex sex, String adres, Integer prioryty, Calendar startStudyYear, Calendar endStudyYear) {
    super(ID, name, surname, academicDeggre, birthDate, age, sex, adres, prioryty);
    this.startStudyYear= startStudyYear;
    this.endStudyYear= endStudyYear;
}
```

Comment: *"I tried using different ways"* Like what? Show us. --- Also show us the fields of `Student`. --- *Hint:* Remove the `cell` loop, and use `row.getCell(int cellnum)` instead.

Comment: You need to construct `Student` object from information read from Excel file and then add that `Student` object into list

Comment: Another hint: or you can use cell.getStringCellValue()  to read string value from excel and assign it to a string property of student object like studentName. Again, you need to post more code or display your student object and what version of POI are you using?

Comment: Studnet Class above. I know that I have to create Student object and put it into list. But how to I get each value, like ID, name, etc. from //Loop for getting data from excel

Answer (score -1):

I would convert the excel file to csv. After you converted it you can select the text inside the csv-file with a filereader (just google it). Afterwards you can seperate the values (they're seperated by a specific sign) with stringbuilder (just google it).